# Is there a non-$0/1$ matrix of this form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose the only constraints of an $n\times n$ matrix are every row has to sum to $1$ and every column has to sum to $1$ is there clever ways to write down non-$0/1$ matrices of this form (preferably over integers)?

What other sum constraints can we add to make it $0/1$?

Answer (score 2):

Start with any matrix that satisfies the condition, like your 0/1-matrices, and then repeatedly add random matrices that consist of all zeroes except in four positions on the corners of a square, where the upper left and lower right corners are identical, and the upper right and lower left corners are identical and opposite:

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&0&0\\
0&2&-2\\
0&-2&2
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&3&-2\\
0&-2&3
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

*(edited after question was extended)*

In order to limit the solutions to 0/1-matrices we need nonlinear constraints. Any set of linear constraints will have a linear space for its solutions, which implies that the number of solutions is zero, one or infinite.

For example, require the additional constraint that the sums of the *squares* also have to be 1.

Comment: he just gave you a perfect guideline, you can figure out your own examples, this is a math forum!